# How to make the header or footer of a ListView not clickable

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I'm adding a footer and header view to a `ListView` by using the methods `setHeaderView()` and `setFooterView()` and a `ViewInflater`. That works quite well.

But how could I prevent the header or footer view from firing `onListItemClick` events? Of course I can catch the event and check whether it came from a header or footer, but this only solves one part of the problem, as header and footer got still focused when clicked.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Simply use the [ListView#addHeaderView(View v, Object data, boolean isSelectable);](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addFooterView%28android.view.View,%20java.lang.Object,%20boolean%29)
 and matching `addFooter()` method.

---

**The purpose of `Object data` parameter.**

The ListView source code describes the `data` parameter as:

> The data backing the view. This is returned from ListAdapter#getItem(int).

Which means if I use `listView.getAdapter().getItem(0);` it will return the `data` Object from our header.

---

I'll elaborate this with an example:

```
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
String[] array = new String[] {"one", "two", "three"};
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array);
```

Next let's add a header and set the adapter:

```
listView.addHeaderView(view, "Potato", false);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Later if we ask:

```
Log.v("ListAdapter", listView.getAdapter().getItem(0));  // output: "Potato" 
Log.v("ArrayAdapter", adapter.getItem(0));               // output: "one"
```

Comment: Ah great! It works. One more question what is the data object for? At the moment I set the data parameter to null. But when I would pass a real object to it what happens to it?

Comment: Right now I don't know, I'm reading the source code and looking online to see how it works. I'll post an update if I figure it out!