# How to make ListView's row's TextView bold

Tags: android, listview, textview, bold

I have a ListView. When I try to make it's row's textview bold - it falls. I try:

```
ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.my_list);

list.setAdapter(someListAdapter);

((TextView) list.getChildAt(0).findViewById(R.id.first_name)).setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
```

I need to do this with only one (headers) row's textviews.

Comment: Did you try to change it inside the adapter? Accessing listview children directly is not a good idea since the views can be reused. You can also use `list.addHeader(view)`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to do this with only one (headers) row's textviews.

Try calling this before calling `addHeaderView(view)`:

```
((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.first_name)).setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
```

---

If you not using `addHeaderView()`, extend your adapter and add a snippet of code like this to `getView()`:

```
if(position == 0)
    ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.first_name)).setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
else
    ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.first_name)).setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
```

(I recommend using a ViewHolder, rather than calling `findViewById()` repeatedly. This is just for a quick example.)

Comment: Sam, how to bind data to addHeaderView(view, data, flag)? In which format it must to be?

Comment: Read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12481083/1267661) for how to use `addHeaderView(View, Object, boolean)`.