# ListView#addHeaderView(View, Object data, boolean isSelectable) - data parameter

Tags: java, android, android-listview

When I try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12480762/how-to-make-the-header-or-footer-of-a-listview-not-clickable/12481083#12481083) - it doesn't work. Why? 
Here is my code:

```
ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.workers_list);

View headersView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listview_row, null);
HashMap<String, String> map = createWorkerHashMap(workerTypes.WORKER, "Імена", "Прізвище", "Стаж", "Дата народження", "Місце роботи", "Наукова ступінь", "Вчене звання", "Розряд");
list.addHeaderView(headersView, (Object) map, false);

List<> workersArrayList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

SimpleAdapter workersListAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, workersArrayList, R.layout.listview_row,
            new String[] {"first_name", "last_name", "experience", "birthday", "job", "academic_degree", "academic_title", "operative_rank"}, new int[] {R.id.first_name, R.id.last_name, R.id.experience, R.id.birthday, R.id.job, R.id.academic_degree, R.id.academic_title, R.id.operative_rank});
list.setAdapter(workersListAdapter);
```

Comment: Please, add more info about what doesn't work in your snippets of code. (Suppose you debugged it)

Comment: This code works (application runs), but I see only empty row. I think my data can't bind on view.

Comment: The second parameter of `addHeaderView()` doesn't do what you expect, I described what it _does_ do in a [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12480762/1267661).

Comment: You need to check your map size after below line:
 HashMap<String, String> map = createWorkerHashMap(workerTypes.WORKER, "Імена", "Прізвище", "Стаж", "Дата народження", "Місце роботи", "Наукова ступінь", "Вчене звання", "Розряд");

Answer (score 0):

There is no magic binding. You will have to setup the view (set labels etc.) yourself.

Comment: So the data parameter is for nothing when adapter isn't ArrayAdapter?

Comment: I guess that you will get it back if you call `getItem(0)` but that's it. It surprises me if it does anything if you have an array adapter.